# After I click on the Update button in Kendo Grid, the insert into the database works but this doesnt cause the grid to exit edit mode

Tags: ajax, kendo-grid

Below is my grid.

If you look at the `save:` event, you'll notice an AJAX call.

This AJAX call IS firing, data IS being inserted into the database and I can even see the alert function going through. However, the grid does not exit edit mode for the row I'm inline editing. I'm not sure what's going on because the error message is terrible. I keep getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined [http://localhost/x/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js:13]
```

Here's the grid:

```
function directorsOrRecipients(e)
{
    awardTitleId = e.data.AwardTitleId;

    var detailRow = e.detailRow;

    detailRow.find(".childTabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: {
            open: { effects: "fadeIn" }
        }
    });

    detailRow.find(".directorsOrRecipients").kendoGrid({
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://localhost/x/api/Awards/directors/" + awardTitleId,
                    type: "GET"
                },
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "AwardDirectorId",
                    fields: {
                        "AwardDirectorId": { editable: false, type: "number" },
                        "namefirstlast": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        "directorsequence": { editable: true, type: "number", validation: { min: 1 } },
                        "isonballot": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        "concatenation": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        "MoreNames": { editable: true, type: "number", validation: { min: 0 } },
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "AwardDirectorId", title: "Award Director Id" },
            { field: "namefirstlast", title: "Name", editor: namesAutoComplete },
            { field: "directorsequence", title: "Director Sequence", format: "{0:n0}" },
            { field: "isonballot", title: "On ballot?", editor: onBallotDropDownEditor },
            { field: "concatenation", title: "Concatenation" },
            { field: "MoreNames", title: "More names?", format: "{0:n0}" },
            { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: 100 }],
        sortable: true,
        sort: { field: "namefirstlast", dir: "desc" },
        editable: "inline",
        toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add New Director/Recipient" }],
        save: function(e)
        {
            debugger;

            if (e.data != "undefined")
            {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/x/api/awards/directors",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: $.parseJSON(directorData)
                }).done(function()
                {
                    alert('done!');
                });
            }

        }
    });

    function onBallotDropDownEditor(container, options)
    {
        var data = [
            { "onBallotId": 1, "onBallotDescription": "Yes" },
            { "onBallotId": 2, "onBallotDescription": "No" }];

        $('<input required data-text-field="onBallotDescription" data-value-field="onBallotDescription" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: false,
                dataSource: data
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Success in Ajax call try this,

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

Comment: This worked. If I put both lines in, the edit mode is exited BUT I still get the same error. Then, if I REMOVE $('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();, it works. So apparently I didn't need the dataSource.read(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In controller update function return an object insted of empty Json, like this it worked for me

```
return Json(ModelState.IsValid ? new object() : ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
```